# What is the name parameter in Pandas Series?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In the doc of [Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html), the use parameter of `name` and `fastpath` is not explained. What do they do?

Comment: If you slice a row from a `DataFrame` using `df.ix[0]`, the resulting object is a `Series` with the original index as `name` attribute. `fastpath` I haven't encountered yet.

Comment: @Finwood Can you give an example?

Comment: The `name` is an attribute of the Series, it becomes more important in a df where the `name` is the name of the column. I can't definitively say what `fastpath` is for but looking at the source code it's an internal flag to test whether the data is a homogenous array to short circuit some of the construction

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `name` argument allows you to give a name to a `Series` object, i.e. to the column. So that when you'll put that in a `DataFrame`, the column will be named according to the `name` parameter.

example:

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series(["A","B","C"], name="foo")

In [2]: s
Out[2]: 
0    A
1    B
2    C
Name: foo, dtype: object

In [3]: pd.DataFrame(s)
Out[4]: 
  foo
0   A
1   B
2   C
```

If you don't give a `name` to your `Series` it will be named automatically. Here it will be a `0` in the `dataframe` object:

```
   0
0  A
1  B
2  C
```

For the `fastpath`, it's an internal parameter and an issue has already been reported :

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6903

Answer (score 3):

There is another usage of the 'name' parameter. I will give an example. In this example we will see that the parameter 'name' could be used as an index name for values.

```
purchase_1 = pd.Series({'Name': 'JJ',
                        'Item': 'A',
                        'Cost': 22.00})
purchase_2 = pd.Series({'Name': 'KK',
                        'Item': 'B',
                        'Cost': 22.50})

dfn = pd.DataFrame([purchase_1, purchase_2], index=['Store X', 'Store Y'])

dfn = dfn.append(pd.Series(data={'Cost': 30.00, 'Item': 'C','Name': 'TT'}, name='Store Y'))
dfn



Out[3]: 
         Cost Item Name
Store X  22.0    A   JJ
Store Y  22.5    B   KK
Store Y  30.0    C   TT
```

Comment: Although I understand the usage of this, I’ve always found that pandas is wrongfully mixing concepts here. I understand their rationale on supporting df.append(pd.Series) for single and multi-index data frames, but shouldn’t they introduce another attribute?
In my opinion code of multi-index data frames would be much cleaner if they split the attribute to name_index, name_value/index_value.
For example on your described case:, if you would have named the index of the data frame “store_idx” the attributes of the series should be: name_index=”store_idx”, name_value/index_value=”Store Y”

Answer (score 2):

The `name` of `pd.Series` become the `column name` when you concat them together. Vice versa, when you extract a column from `dataframe`, it has the `column name` as the name of the extracted `pd.Series`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10), name='series1')
s2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10), name='series2')
pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)

Out[16]: 
   series1  series2
0   0.3499   0.3017
1  -2.2980  -1.1121
2  -1.4517  -0.5107
3  -0.4596  -0.0855
4  -0.3230   0.5391
5  -0.1764  -0.3218
6   2.4806  -0.6129
7   1.6766   1.1408
8  -1.2407   0.4857
9   0.3587  -1.5752
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to all the information, I just learned that when you have to append a row using Series, two options are there:
1) ignore_index = True, in this case, it will remove the set index and reset it to numeric index (default)
2) using the name helps to keep the current dataframe structure and use the name parameter as the multi index (in order).