# scipy.optimize.minimize executed multiple times on some rows when being applied to a pandas data frame with or without multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to find the optimal point of a function for each row of a data frame using `spicy.optimize.minimize`'s `L-BFGS-B` method, I print the optimal point for each iteration and noticed that some rows have been calculated to find optimal point for twice.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b': [7,8,9,10,11,12]})

def func(x, row):
    '''
    calculate result of function
    '''
    return (x - row['a'])*(x - row['b'])

def optimize_func(row):
    '''
    get optimal point
    '''
    res = minimize(func, x0=0, args=row, bounds=[(-10, 10)], method='L-BFGS-B')
    print res.x[0]
    row['optimal_x'] = res.x[0]
    return row

data = data.apply(optimize_func, axis=1)
```

The output is as follows:

```
4.000000039384161
4.000000039384161
4.99999996369956
5.999999857891461
6.999999889918595
7.99999992894573
8.999999928945726
```

You can see that the first row has been calculated for optimal points for twice.

I'm applying the `minimize` function on each row, could anybody suggest a possible reason for this? Thanks!

In order to save time to find optimal point for an equation calculated from each row of a data frame, I'm using `multiprocessing` to speed it up. However, after using `multiprocessing`, optimization on each row will be executed twice, below is a sample code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from contextlib import closing
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b': [7,8,9,10,11,12]})

def func(x, row):
    '''
    calculate result of function 1
    '''
    return (x - row['a'])*(x - row['b'])

def optimize_func(row):
    res = minimize(func, x0=0, args=row, bounds=[(-10, 10)], method='L-BFGS-B')
    print res.x[0]
    row['optimal_x'] = res.x[0]
    return row

def apply_optimize_func(data):
    '''
    prepare for multiprocessing
    '''
    return data.apply(optimize_func, axis=1)

def get_optimize_x(data):
    '''
    apply multiprocessing
    '''
    df_parts = np.array_split(data, 20)
    with closing(Pool(processes=10)) as pool:
        result_parts = pool.map(apply_optimize_func, df_parts)
    data = pd.concat(result_parts)
    return data

data = get_optimize_x(data)
```

in order to show that the optimization is executed twice for each row, I added a `print` statement to `optimize_func()` and the printed optimal points are as follows:

```
4.000000039384161
4.000000039384161
4.99999996369956
4.99999996369956
5.999999857891461
5.999999857891461
6.999999889918595
6.999999889918595
7.99999992894573
7.99999992894573
8.999999928945726
8.999999928945726
```

as you can see, each point is generated twice, I'm wondering why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Does `apply` say anything about performing a trial calculation?  to determine the return type/size?

Comment: Did you read this note in the `apply` docs?  `n the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path.`

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj , that solves my problem! I'm wondering if I could force it to take a fast path? Thanks!

Comment: One SO ref to fastpath https://stackoverflow.com/q/31292140/901925.  It appears to have something to do with how or where the results are stored.  It has nothing to do with how they are calculated - that is, it won't speed up your `minimize` calls.